# How to get MYSAPSSO2 Cookie with SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

im trying to get MYSAPSSO2 Cookie from a Portal.

I test with Postman and i can see the cookie in the Cookies Tab:

Screenshots from postman:

[image: Results]

Headers:

[image]

And here are the parameters i'm passing in the body and header

[image]

[image]

Now the problem is that i can't get the same values from JavaScript. Postman gives the code snipet to call the service like this:

[image]

Then if i try to execute this from my application i get this:

[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MYSAPSSO2 cookie is `httpOnly`. This means that it cannot be accessed from a client.

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly

However you can create new tokens in the backend with the function module `CREATE_RFC_REENTRANCE_TICKET` and expose them via OData.

Comment: I've solved my problem, the problem was that the browser handles automatically the cookie MYSAPSSO2. i.e: if you make a post to your portal after that you can call every service you want without passing the cookie because the browser handle it automatically. Regards.